# How can I remove Milliseconds from the TimeSpan in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and using windows forms. the result of this code is: `01:38:07.0093844` . Anyone knows how can I remove the millisecond part (0093844) from the result (ts) I want the result to look like this : `01:38:07` (H:mm:ss) without millisecond .

Please help .Thank you

```
string OldDateTime = "2016-03-02 13:00:00.597"; //old DateTime
DateTime CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan  ts = CurrentDateTime.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(OldDateTime)); //Difference

//result of ts = 01:38:07.0093844
```

Comment: What do you mean "look like"? Do you mean when converting it to a string? Or what?

Comment: When you say the result of ts is 01:38:07.0093844, you mean after ToString()? I mean, you want to strip milliseconds of timespan or to show it as a string?

Comment: You should use formatting it it is only for display purposes, please check the MSDN documentation page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you talking about string formatting? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: or DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()  or ShortDateString / or format

Comment: If you want to result just *looks like* then use formatting when representing the `TimeSpan` as a `String`

Comment: @ Ben . yes after ToSting();

Comment: @ Pikoh . yes please.

Comment: @kate, you've got now a lot of answers below

Comment: @Kate look at the Extension method, easy to reuse again

Comment: this is the correct answer:  TimeSpan trimmedTimeNow = new TimeSpan(ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds); it gives you the day difference too

Comment: Use substring method and get only 8 chars `(yourTimeSpan).ToString().Substring(0,8)`. I found this much cleaner in the code than the weird format thats required to output this using TimeSpan.

Answer (score 20):

Create an extension method:

```
public static class TimeExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan StripMilliseconds(this TimeSpan time)
    {
        return new TimeSpan(time.Days, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string OldDateTime = "2016-03-02 13:00:00.597"; //old DateTime
DateTime CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan  ts = CurrentDateTime.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(OldDateTime)).StripMilliseconds();
```

To format (make into a string) without milliseconds use this:

```
string OldDateTime = "2016-03-02 13:00:00.597"; //old DateTime
DateTime CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan  ts = CurrentDateTime.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(OldDateTime));
string formatted = ts.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: You are assuming he knows how to use Extension Methods, add an example how it will work

Comment: still did not work for me. the Subtract() does not have function called StripMillisecond . anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: StripMilliseconds is an extension method you need to declare in your code (see my first code snippet). More about extension methods -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can round through a division and a multiplication by the number of Ticks per second:

```
ts = new TimeSpan(ts.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
```

Internally a `TimeSpan` is "simply" a number of `Ticks`. By doing an integer division and an integer multiplication you can "round" them.

Comment: @ xanatos. I used your code but the millisecond still there they set to 00000. any idea? tnx

Answer (score 6):

What the object contains and what you want on the screen are separate concerns, do not mix the 2. If you want it formatted on the screen as hourse, minutes, seconds then use `ToString()` and include that in your format. Example:

```
var forScreen = ts.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

See all the formatting options available on [MSDN Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Edit

As mentioned, you can make it whatever you want. Here is an example of ToString which builds out a human readable string. These formatters are meant to build a string that you can display so you do not have to actually make changes to the underlying data. This is your presentation logic.

```
dif.ToString("'Elapsed: 'dd' days, 'hh' hours, 'mm' minutes and 'ss' seconds'")
```

Comment: ok, but will this work if the result has days? like 3 days 2h 23mm 12ss

Comment: @Kate no it won't, if you want to have a specific formatting please read one of the two documentation links so that you can make your own

Comment: @Kate - sure, you can use `ToString` to do whatever you want. As Sidewinder mentioned, figure out how you want to display it to the user, read the documentation, and create your own format string.

Answer (score 1):

You can just format the time like below:

```
string NewDateTime = ts.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: That will not work, String is not type of TimeSpan

Comment: @DonaldJansen Oh my bad, quickly typed it. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: That's not right. He wants to show the TimeSpan,not OldDateTime

Comment: If we want to go that way the format is not the one the OP asked, it's still a good help to know which way to go :)

Comment: @Pikoh He says in his question "_I want the result to look like this : 01:38:07 (H:mm:ss) without millisecond_".

Comment: @BenClarke yes, the result, not OldDateTime

Comment: @Pikoh I don't understand, `OldDateTime` will not change? The `NewDateTime` will be set to the new format?

Comment: @BenClarke what i'm trying to say it should be `ts.ToString(..`  , not `OldDateTime.ToString(...` He wants to show the timespan result of substracting CurrentDateTime from OldDateTime

Comment: @Pikoh Ahh sorry, i was misreading what you were saying. My bad.